# Does this df -h output mean i have a ~ 140G area available?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive

I'm creating a AWS server from a ubuntu AMI - it didn't say how much disk space was allocated so I ran `df -h` and got the following result:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1            7.9G  645M  6.9G   9% /
none                  828M  116K  828M   1% /dev
none                  833M     0  833M   0% /dev/shm
none                  833M   40K  833M   1% /var/run
none                  833M     0  833M   0% /var/lock
/dev/xvda2            147G  188M  140G   1% /mnt
```

Does this mean I have a 140G disk in /mnt? I'm not really sure what that means when `/` is only 7.9g.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I looks like `/` and `/mnt` are 2 partitions of the same disk. The partition mounted on `/mnt` is in fact 147GB in size, with 140GB free.

Answer (score 3):

I recognize this as an Amazon EC2 m1.small instance. The / partition is likely your 8GB EBS volume and the /mnt partition is the transient storage included with m1.small. Data in /mnt will be lost when the instance is shut down.

Comment: old question, but yes that's what I eventually figured out. :) Actually using it to store images which are processed and auto-deleted when they are over an hour old, now.

Answer (score 2):

`xvdXX` is the naming convention for AWS EBS devices.

`df` isn't the best command to see what's on your system - try something like `fdisk -l` (as root)